# How to get sorted Dictionary from MutableArray using swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I manage to create a dictionary from my database to add sections in `tableview`.

My function get the database into Array and the Array into dictionary (A: Aname1,Aname2, B: Bname1,Bname2...).
When I sorted my dictionary the return value is type [String, [String]] and I need it to be [String: [String]], when I don't use the sort action it's give this error:

> Thread1:EXC_BAS_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

In the console:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>       (lldb)

My code:

```
class SectionData {

    var marrCrimesNames : NSMutableArray!

    func getCrimesNames() {
        marrCrimesNames = NSMutableArray()
        marrCrimesNames = ModelManager.getInstance().getAllCrimesNames()
    }

    func getSectionsFromData() -> [String: [String]] {

        var sectionDictionary =  [String: [String]]()

        let crime: CrimesInfo = (marrCrimesNames.object(at: 0) as! CrimesInfo) // Thread1:EXC_BAS_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
        _ = crime.Name
        var firstLetter: [String] = []

        for crime in marrCrimesNames {
            firstLetter.append((crime as AnyObject).Name)
        }

        let characters = Array(Set(firstLetter.flatMap({ $0.characters.first })))

        for character in characters.map({ String($0) }) {
            sectionDictionary[character] = firstLetter.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(character) })
        }

        //var sortedSectionDictionary = sectionDictionary.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
        // sort action return [String, [String]]

        return sectionDictionary
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would first create an object `marrCrimesNames = NSMutableArray()` only then to override it with `marrCrimesNames = ModelManager.getInstance().getAllCrimesNames()`?
Any change the `ModelManager.getInstance().getAllCrimesNames()` return object is not mutable?

Comment: `marrCrimesNames.object(at: 0)` is nil (`marrCrimesNames`has zero elements).

Comment: I just checked and its not contains any zeros and its mutable

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you assume that the value return in:
`let crime: CrimesInfo = (marrCrimesNames.object(at: 0) as! CrimesInfo)` is set.

The error clearly show that it is not set and return `nil`.
So check it:

```
if let crime = marrCrimesNames.object(at: 0) {
   // Here you can safely use crime ;)
}
```

Comment: Why when i used (uncomment) the     var sortedSectionDictionary = sectionDictionary.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })     it doesn't show me the error?     is there any way to convert type ([String, [String]]) into ([String: [String]])?

Answer (score 0):

You need two check two things

1. first check if marrCrimesNames != nil, put a guard statement to check nil
2. What type of object marrCrimesNames has, are you sure it has CrimesInfo objects?
3. To know what type of object marrCrimesNames has just hold a reference of 0th index and check the type of object in degugger in left side debug panel.